# FIle Sound not found, and return java.lang.NullPointer Exception

Tags: java, file, audio

I have tried putting the .wav file on the separate modules title sound, putting it in the same packages with the program, and putting it in src. I checked using command prompt and the file is playable. I also make sure that .wav is supported by Java. What I'm confused about is,  it did not return FileNotFound exception, but NullPointer Exception. What is it that I am doing wrong? Beforehand, thank you for those who can help.

Here is my source code:

````
    Clip brickCollisionSound;
    Clip gameMusicSound;
    Clip gameWinSound;
    Clip paddleCollisionSound;
    Clip wallCollisionSound;
    
    private void initSounds() {
        try {
            File soundFile = new File("./gameOver.wav");
            //URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sound/gameOver.wav");
            AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
            gameOverSound = AudioSystem.getClip();
            gameOverSound.open(audioIn);

            soundFile = new File("./BrickCollission.wav");
            //url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sound/BrickCollission.wav");
            audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
            brickCollisionSound = AudioSystem.getClip();
            brickCollisionSound.open(audioIn);

            soundFile = new File("./gameMusic.wav");
            //url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sound/gameMusic.wav");
            audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
            gameMusicSound = AudioSystem.getClip();
            gameMusicSound.open(audioIn);
            
            soundFile = new File("./gameWin.wav");
            //url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sound/gameWin.wav");
            audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
            gameWinSound = AudioSystem.getClip();
            gameWinSound.open(audioIn);
            
            soundFile = new File("./PaddleCollision.wav");
            //url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sound/PaddleCollision.wav");
            audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
            paddleCollisionSound = AudioSystem.getClip();
            paddleCollisionSound.open(audioIn);
            
            soundFile = new File("./WallCollision.wav");
            //url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sound/WallCollision.wav");
            audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
            wallCollisionSound = AudioSystem.getClip();
            wallCollisionSound.open(audioIn);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException e) {
        }
    }
    
    public void playMusic() {
        gameMusicSound.setMicrosecondPosition(0);
        gameMusicSound.start();
        gameMusicSound.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }

    public void stopMusic() {
        if (gameMusicSound.isRunning()) gameMusicSound.stop();
    }
    
    public void playGameOverSound() {
        gameOverSound.setMicrosecondPosition(0);
        gameOverSound.start();
    }
    
    public void playGameWinSound() {
        gameWinSound.setMicrosecondPosition(0);
        gameWinSound.start();
    }

    public void playBrickCollisionSound() {
        brickCollisionSound.setMicrosecondPosition(0);
        brickCollisionSound.start();
    }
    
    public void playPaddleCollisionSound() {
        paddleCollisionSound.setMicrosecondPosition(0);
        paddleCollisionSound.start();
    }
    
    public void playWallCollisionSound() {
        wallCollisionSound.setMicrosecondPosition(0);
        wallCollisionSound.start();
    }
     ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `File soundFile = new File("./gameOver.wav");`

this attempts to find that file in the 'current working directory'. What that is depends on the user, and thus, this isn't how you do that. Delete these lines.

> `URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sound/gameOver.wav");`

That's also not how you do that.

It's:

```
package com.foo;

class Foobar {
    private void initSounds() {
        Foobar.class.getResource("sounds/gameOver.wav");
    }
}
```

This looks for a directory named `sounds` which should be in the same place that the file `Foobar.class` is in (even if it is in a jar or jmod file, that's fine). In other words, if you have a jar with that, you'd have `com/foo/Foobar.class` and `com/foo/sounds/gameOver.wav` in that jar file. If you prefer to from the root of the jar, you can do that: `.getResource("/sounds/gameOver.wav")` (note the leading slash) would look in the same jar/dir/etc. So if your Foobar.class is currently running from `/Users/Khaela/workspace/game-project/bin/com/foo/Foobar.class`, then the sounds file is looked for in `/Users/Khaela/workspace/game-project/bin/sound/gameOver.wav`.

Note that maven and most other build tools copy the files from `src/main/resources` over the same way that IDEs and tools compile files over from `src/main/java`. Thus, put them there (if using `.getResource("sounds/gameOver.wav")`, make sure `src/main/resources/foo/bar/gameOver.wav` exists). IDEs with maven plugins will figure it out and make it work, too.

> ```
> } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | >LineUnavailableException e) {
> }
> ```

This is incredibly silly code. Don't catch exceptions if you don't know what to do (unless you rethrow them), and definitely don't catch exceptions and completely ignore them. It's confused you so much it led you to asking questions on SO. **Do not write catch blocks like this**.

The right 'I dunno what to do!' catch block is this:

```
} catch (SomethingYouHaveNoClueAbout e) {
   throw new RuntimeException("Uncaught", e);
}
```

This ends execution (you want that - bad things happened, don't just continue on blindly, with half of the code you ran so far not having done what you wanted it to do, and no idea which half or what failed - continuing on with code execution is a very bad idea under those circumstances, obviously) - and preserves *ALL* information about the problem (which is a lot: Message, exception type, stack trace, causal chain, suppressed list, and depending on the exception even more info).